# Qt 3D scatter graph: how can I adjust the scale of an axis?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm currently developing a Qt desktop application using the Q3DScatter class. I'm inspecting Qt's 3D Scatter example project and I tried to modify the data item set to plot my own data. The data is plotted except that one axis is not well scaled and my 3D plot looks really messy. I'm looking for a way to adjust this axis. I've tried to change the range and the segment count of the axis, I even tried to set the "AutoAdjustRange" of the axis to true, but nothing seemed to solve the problem.

Would really appreciate some help.

PS: Here's a screen capture of what my 3D scatter graph looks like (the "messy" axis is shown with the red arrow)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out by creating a `CustomFormatter` class by subclassing `QValue3DAxisFormatter` and reimplementing some of its functions (I followed [this tutorial](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdatavisualization-qmlaxisformatter-example.html)). Then I set up my axis formatter to my custom formatter (`m_graph->axisZ()->setFormatter(cf);`).

Answer (score 2):

Subclassing `QValue3DAxisFormatter` will not work: it determines where ticks and labels are placed, but not how large the axex actually are.

To do that, you can set the (horizontal) aspect ratio, that is a property of `Q3DScatter`. The following settings will make the data into a cube volume:

```
plot->setAspectRatio(1.0);
plot->setHorizontalAspectRatio(1.0);
```